# Keep an image visible inside a cardView on a recyclerView after rotating device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make a simple Android app in Kotlin to a school project that shows some images from the internet.
The images are being showed inside a cardView, on a recyclerView with a grid layout.

In each cardView I'm getting a random image from picsum and I also have a star icon for marking the image as favourite.
The purpose of this work is to work with sharedPreferences.
So I have to store which image is being set as favourite (there only can be one at time), and store that position that whenever I rotate the device, the icon stays visible.

How should I store this and in which function should I call the sharedPreferences data to display the icon?

**Adapter.kt**

```
package com.example.bottomnavigationapp.fragimages.ui

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.bottomnavigationapp.R
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class GridItemAdapter(
    val cardImages: Array<String>,
    private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<GridItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
    View.OnClickListener{

        val cardImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImage)
        val favImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favImage)

        init {
            cardImage.setOnClickListener(this)
        }


        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            var position : Int = adapterPosition
            val address = cardImages[position]
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position, favImage, address)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_view, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso.get().load(cardImages[position]).into(holder.cardImage)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cardImages.size
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int, favImage: ImageView, address: String)
    }
}
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
package com.example.bottomnavigationapp.fragimages.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.bottomnavigationapp.R
import com.example.bottomnavigationapp.databinding.FragmentImagesBinding

class ImagesFragment : Fragment(), GridItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentImagesBinding
    var hasFavourite : Int = -1



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentImagesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val cardImages : Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.cardImages)
        val adapter = GridItemAdapter(cardImages, this)
        val gridLayout = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        binding.gridItems.layoutManager = gridLayout
        binding.gridItems.adapter = adapter

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.title = "Images Fragment"
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int, favImage: ImageView, address: String) {
        if (hasFavourite < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Address: $address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val favAddress = address
            val favStatus = true

            val sharedPreferences = requireActivity().applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0)
            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

            editor.apply {
                putString("favAddress", address)
                putBoolean("favStatus", favStatus)
            }

            favImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            hasFavourite = position
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item $position set to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
         else if (hasFavourite == position) {
            favImage.visibility = View.GONE
            hasFavourite = -1
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Favourite already set at position $hasFavourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are trying to set preferences all the time but not getting them. Create seperate class named "UserPreferences.kt" and paste below code in it:

```
 class UserPreferences {
    // Store all Sharedpreferences methods in here
    fun getPositionPref(fragment: Fragment): Int {
        return fragment.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            "myPref",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        ).getInt(
            "positionPref",
            -1
        )
    }

    fun setPositionPref(fragment: Fragment, position: Int) {
        val sharedPreferences =
            fragment.requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                "myPref",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            )
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putInt(
            "positionPref",
            position
        )
        editor.apply()
    }
}
```

Coming to your code let's make some adjustments:

```
class ImagesFragment : Fragment(), GridItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentImagesBinding
    //edited
    private var hasFavourite : Int = -1

   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentImagesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        hasFavourite = UserPreferences().getPositionPref(this)
        // Now you get what's in sharedPreferences.
        // If it's first time it will be -1 for default.
        val cardImages : Array<String> = 
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.cardImages)
        val adapter = GridItemAdapter(cardImages, this, hasFavourite)
        // send hasFavourite to adapter too.
        val gridLayout = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        binding.gridItems.layoutManager = gridLayout
        binding.gridItems.adapter = adapter

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.title = "Images Fragment"
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int, favImage: ImageView, address: String) {
        if (hasFavourite == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Address: $address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            UserPreferences().setPositionPref(this, position)
            // Now we set it to position, for another time you wanna get

            //putString("favAddress", address)
            //putBoolean("favStatus", favStatus)
            //For this two, you need to create it's own functions in 
            // UserPreferences class we created, you got the idea
            
            favImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            hasFavourite = UserPreferences().getPositionPref(this)
            // We get the new value of hasFavourite from shared pref again.
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item $position set to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
         else if (hasFavourite == position) {
            favImage.visibility = View.GONE
            //edited
            UserPreferences().setPositionPref(this, -1)
            hasFavourite = UserPreferences().getPositionPref(this)
           // We set it to default, there should be no item favorited
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Favourite already set at position $hasFavourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

So let's say you chose one favorite and close the app and open again, it won't  start with favorite applied to adapter until you click one of the items to solve this in beginning we sent hasFavourite to adapter:

```
class GridItemAdapter(
    val cardImages: Array<String>,
    private val listener: OnItemClickListener,
    private val hasFavourite: Int) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<GridItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

   // and onBind we check and set:
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso.get().load(cardImages[position]).into(holder.cardImage)
        if (hasFavourite == position) {
          holder.favImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
   }
```

I think this should do the trick, haven't tried, if not works let me know.

Comment: Hi Mert, thanks for the help, and I think that I understood the logic, I only started on Kotlin about a month ago and this is all new to me.
About your code, I'm getting 2 errors on my ImagesFragment. the first is about not being able to declare a lateinit if it is Int type, (private lateinit var hasFavourite: Int).
The second is on the same fragment, fun OnItemClick, on else if, I'm having a type mismatch:
Required:
Int
Found:
Unit

Comment: I corrected them, should work now. The key point is the get data and set data with sharedPreferences all the time, not on the local variables. When you changed orientation of the screen, your fragment will recreate and do all it's staff again and forget what you did to favorite images. You save them to shared preferences and get from them after recreate to continue where you left.

Comment: Thanks Mert, just one more question, I want to keep the position of the favourite image when I rotate the screen or change the fragment, but if I want to set the favourite to position 0 when the app is restarted in wich method should I implement that logic? So when i set the favourite, change the screen or change the fragment I want to keep position, but when I restart the app I want to set it to 0. I've tried a lot of methods (onDestroy, onStop, onCreate) but all have the same behaviour closing the app or rotating the screen.

Comment: That's because when you rotate screen or relaunch app, your fragment's `onCreateView` triggers, i mean it will rebuild, so it will get data again, and every time the sorting of elements maybe different. Best approach is to use mvvm pattern and viewmodel. It only gets data one time and will not lose it when screen rotates. It can be a little bit advanced. Another method that came into my mind is easier. You can sort your values from internet after you get them, and then send to recyclerview, with this all the time recyclerview receive the sorted. Example sort by image name or id.